# ASP.NET WebAPI - File Upload with FormData doesn't have all the form data fields

Tags: react-native, asp.net-web-api, owin, axios, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file with some form data using `axios` in React-Native as `multipart/form-data` to ASP.NET Web API.

I've followed this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2

and I'm reading the file and form data using `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` which seems to be getting both the file and form data. However, the form data isn't complete. For example, I'm sending about 14 fields to the server, but I'm only getting 7 when I try to read it through `provider.FormData`.

### My React Native / Axios Code

```
var dataToSubmit = new FormData();

// Have about 14 fields in the FormData
dataToSubmit.append('Key1', 'value1');
dataToSubmit.append('Key2', 'value2');
dataToSubmit.append('Key3', 'value3');
.
.
dataToSubmit.append('Key14', 'value14');

// Have 1 file in the FormData
dataToSubmit.append('File', {
   uri: filePath,
   type: 'image/jpeg',
   name: fileName
});

axios({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'URL to post',
   data: dataToSubmit,
   headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
}).then((response) => {
   console.log(response);
});
```

### My Request

I have a debugger on the phone and I saw the following request (with all the 14 fields and the file)

```
POST /api/urltopost HTTP/1.1
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
boundary=BOUNDARY_GUID
Content-Length: 53038
Host: HOST_IP
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip

--BOUNDARY_GUID
content-disposition: form-data; name="Key1"
Content-Length: 24

--BOUNDARY_GUID
content-disposition: form-data; name="Key2"
Content-Length: 24

..

..

--BOUNDARY_GUID
content-disposition: form-data; name="File"
filename="test.jpg",
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 50626
```

### My ASP.NET Web API Code

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData(DTO obj)
{
   if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
   {
      throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
   }

   string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
   var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

   try
   {
       await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

       // Show all the key-value pairs.
       foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
       {
           foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
           {
               Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
           }
       }

       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   }
   catch (System.Exception e)
   {
      return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
   }
}
```

When I look at `provider`, it shows `Contents` with count 8, `FileData` with count 1 and `FormData` with 7 fields. **But I seem to be missing other 7 fields.**

**NOTE:**

1. I'm using OWIN
2. I tried uploading files from 21 KB to 5.2 MB. I always get the 8 contents. I even tried `multipart/form-data` submission without the file and I still get only those fields.
3. I have the following in my `web.config` to set request limit, which seems to have no impact with the buffer size of the provider -

   ```
   <!-- Under system.webServer -->
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>

   <!-- Under system.web -->
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="2097152" />
   ```
4. I tried using `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider` and it still gets the 8 contents.
5. I tried using Postman and I'm still getting the form data in chunk / 8 fields.
6. I tried setting the buffer size to `5120000` (since it's `4098` by default) for `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` and I still get only those 8 fields. I can't seem to find why the other form fields aren't showing up / I can't get the value for them on the server side. I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything wrong on the client side, since it's not working with Postman either. So I'm guessing it's just the way I'm reading Multipart data on the API.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing / doing wrong? Why am I not seeing all the fields that are sent through the form?

Comment: I Know that this is and old question ... but didn't you tried to dot it using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` and  `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` ?

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't figure out why the entire form data was not being submitted. So here is my workaround -

I'm making 2 calls to save the data -

1. A `x-www-form-urlencoded` request to save the `FormData`. I get the record ID / key from this save.
2. A `multipart/form-data` request to save the file with the key / identifier

Comment: can you explain please, how you are creating the second API in .net and calling it from React-native?